# Selecting more graphics at once

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, legend, graphics

I'm making a map on ArcMap and I converted the legend to graphics in order to manually manage my symbols and texts. For instance I want to increase the size of all the points in the legend to the same value. If I ungroup all elements I can then select all points one by one keeping control key pressed and then change the size for all of them in one move. Then I would need to regroup all the elements together in order to be able to move the legend around as a single piece. The problem is I couldn't find a way to select more graphics at once, for example with a rectangular selection. That would save me much time especially when regrouping.
Alternatively, is there a faster method to do this whole operation (changing legend items size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hold the `SHIFT` Button down while you draw a  rectangular over the elements.

Fore more details see the ArcGIS help, [Using mouse shortcuts in the table of contents](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00660000025m000000).

> Shift+click selects all layers or data frames between two layers or data frames within the same table of contents level.

Comment: Too simple. There's no challenge in it ;)